# Accessing attributes of Chef::Provider::Package subclass instance from recipe

Tags: chef-infra

I need to somehow "return" variable from custom subclass of `Chef::Provider::Package` back to the recipe it is called from, so I can use this variable later in the same recipe.

I tried to add custom `Chef::Resource::Package` subclass attribute and appropriate setter/getter wrapper with `set_or_return` function. I can successfully write and read this attribute from my `Chef::Provider::Package` subclass, but when I try to access this attribute from recipe all I see is `nil` value. This can be illustrated with the following recipe:

```
a = apt_package "bzip2" do
  action :install
end

# this won't work, a.version would be nil
log "bzip package version is #{a.version}"
```

However, I can see in `lib/chef/provider/package/apt.rb` that `@current_resource.version` is being set:

```
@current_resource.version(installed_version)
```

What is the right way of reading arbitrary attribute (`version` in this example) of `Chef::Resource::AptPackage` instance, created by `apt_package` provider from the same recipe?

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like::

```
a = apt_package "bzip2" do
          action :install
      end

      ruby_block "Init logger" do
        block do
          logger= resources("log[printing version]")
          logger.message a.version
        end
      end

      log "printing version" do
        message ""
       end
```